# Sub works when run but not when called? "Select method of Range Class failed"

Tags: excel, vba

This Sub works.

```
Sub SalesPDF()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, WdObj As Object, ws As Worksheet, EquitiesRow As Range, RowEnd As Range, BondRow As Range
    j = 0
    k = 0
    Set ws = Worksheets("PnL")
    Set SalesBrokerage = Worksheets("SalesBrokerage")
    SalesBrokerage.Cells(6 + k, 9).Value = MarketFinder(SalesBrokerage.Cells(6 + k, 10))
    k = k + 2
    Next i
    'blablabla...........
    SalesBrokerage.Range("b1,c1,f1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    For i = 2 To 7
        SalesBrokerage.Columns(7 + i).ColumnWidth = SalesBrokerage.Columns(i).ColumnWidth
    Next i
    Call Excel2PDF
End Sub
```

I do not have a problem when running the code beneath by itself.

When I run `SalesPDF()` and `Excel2PDF()` is called I get the error message

> Select method of Range Class failed

in `SalesBrokerage.Range("B1:N" & SalesBrokerage.Cells(SalesBrokerage.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Select`

```
Sub Excel2PDF()
Set SalesBrokerage = Worksheets("SalesBrokerage")
SalesBrokerage.Range("B1:N" & SalesBrokerage.Cells(SalesBrokerage.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Me.pdf" Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Why does it not work when running `SalesPDF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `ActiveWorkbook` vs `ThisWorkbook` issue. When you don't fully qualify a sheet/range object the code will assume it's in the **active** workbook.

When you're running the code manually, chances are you're making that workbook the active one so it runs fine.

`ActiveWorkbook` = the workbook that's currently active (usually the same workbook that is in view to the user)

`ThisWorkbook` = the workbook that the executing code belongs to.

---

If your code is in the same workbook as the sheet you're referring to then qualify it like so:

```
Set SalesBrokerage = Worksheets("SalesBrokerage")
```

You can also make your code a bit more readable by refactoring with a `With` block:

```
With SalesBrokerage
    With .Range("B1:N" & .Cells(SalesBrokerage.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Me.pdf" Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
End With
```